# I'm not getting desired output for Armstrong number in elixir

Tags: elixir

I wrote code to find whether a number is an `Armstrong` number or not.
A positive integer is called an `Armstrong` number of order `n` if the sum of cubes of each digit is equal to the number itself.
For example:

> 153 = 1 ^ 3 + 5 ^ 3 + 3 ^ 3  // 153 is an Armstrong number.

```
defmodule IsArmstrong do
    def cube(number) do
        :math.pow(number, 3) |> round
    end

    def digit_cube_sum(number) do
        Enum.sum(Enum.map(Integer.digits(number), &cube/1))
    end

    def is_armstrong(number) do
        if number == &digit_cube_sum/1 do
            IO.puts("Armstrong number")
        else
            IO.puts("Not an armstrong number")
        end
    end
end
```

Irrespective of what number I give as an argument, I keep getting `"Not an Armstrong number"`. Help me find
where the code is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here,

```
number == &digit_cube_sum/1
```

you're comparing the number `number` to the function `digit_cube_sum/1`.
These are never equal.

You need to call the function with the appropriate argument and compare to the result,

```
number == digit_cube_sum(number)
```